# How do you run npm dev on local network, with Vite and Laravel?

Tags: vite

I serve my laravel app on this ip: 192.168.1.9:25565
For vite, I've found this on other forums: `npm run dev -- --host`
it says

```
➜  Local:   http://localhost:5173/
  ➜  Network: http://[MY_IP_HERE]:5173/
  ➜  Network: http://192.168.1.9:5173/
```

so I should be able to basically go to 192.168.1.9:25565, and see my site as I'd run it simply with npm run dev and php artisan serve.

I can't see the CSS and the JS tho, and I don't want to spam npm run build all the time I make some adjustments (since I'm making the mobile version, and it's easier to test it on my phone than with devtools responsivity).

Am I missing something? Everything is on local network, I can access the site, but the css-js.

vite.config.jg

```js
import { defineConfig } from 'vite';
import laravel from 'laravel-vite-plugin';

export default defineConfig({
    plugins: [
        laravel({
            input: ['resources/css/app.css', 'resources/js/app.js'],
            refresh: true,
        }),
    ],
});
```

Comment: Can you share more details about the missing css and js? What kind of errors do you get in your browsers console?

Comment: just a regular app.css and app.js in the default laravel structure. I get no errors besides these: https://imgur.com/a/Nez7NRa and this the vite import I have in my blade, as suggested by vite:     @vite(['resources/css/app.css', 'resources/js/app.js']) (even if I change these to public/*, it won't make a difference)

Comment: Did you replace the IP address of the GET request with `[::]` or is it missing? Otherwise could it be a configuration issue in your `vite.config.js` ?

Comment: No, seems like its missing. 
For clarity, I ran these commands, as intructed: `npm run dev -- --host` , and `php artisan serve --host 192.168.1.9 --port 25565` .

I added my vite.config.js, but still, it's like the out-of-the-box config.

Comment: I guess something in the serve-part goes wrong (build in PHP etc). An easy way to run Laravel locally is using a DDEV docker environment - you could try that.

Comment: I'm on windows, so idk. I also want it to be open on the local network (as mentioned in post), so idk how that would work.